# Create A Column with Value Based on Function Input

Tags: r, function, lapply

This question has sort of been asked multiple times, including in this example: [Lapply to Add Columns to Each Dataframe in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901597/lapply-to-add-columns-to-each-dataframe-in-a-list).

However, I simply want to add an argument within a function that creates a new column, and that column has a value based on input.

```
dfs<-lapply(clients_names, function(x){

df<-read.csv(...),

##this is when I want to add a column to the df loaded,
##a column of clients with names their names)

return(df)
})
```

I tried using `df$clients<- x` in place of `##` but that did not work.

**UPDATE**:

```
client_names<-c("Bob", "Sam", "Chris")
```

Comment: Since your basic premise of `df$clients <- x` is fine, it must be something else. Can you show more code that indicates how you make `x`?

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*temp*`, "column", value = "Bob"): replacement has 1 row, data has 0.

Comment: This error means that `df` is empty, so your problem is elsewhere. (Try `df <- data.frame(a=1,b=2)[0,] ; df ; df$c <- 3` for a simple reproduction.)

Comment: I don't know. Some debugging might be in order. To find out which of your `client_names` is showing the problem, you might want to add `message(x)` as the first line in your function, then run it. If the name that shows the problem is not the first one in the vector, then add something like `if (x == "Sam") browser()` so that you can easily get to the problem element in the list. Either way, there's not much I can do here without having all of your files (not asking) or seeing more code and sample data.

Comment: Hey @r2evans. Thank you for your advice. After checking what you recommended, it worked since I found the bug! I initially doubted that function even though I used it before. Thanks!